# How to read events/entries added to calendar?

Tags: android

I am able to add entries as of now. In my app, the user can enter an appointment/event on his calendar. But before he can do that, it should show him the events he has already added. it should fetch the events from calendar and show it to him. How to do this? I am stuck at this part.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), new String[]{ "calendar_id", "title", "description", "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }, null, null, null);         
    //Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "name" }, null, null, null);
    String add = null;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String[] CalNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    int[] CalIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < CalNames.length; i++) {
        CalIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
        CalNames[i] = "Event"+cursor.getInt(0)+": \nTitle: "+ cursor.getString(1)+"\nDescription: "+cursor.getString(2)+"\nStart Date: "+new Date(cursor.getLong(3))+"\nEnd Date : "+new Date(cursor.getLong(4))+"\nLocation : "+cursor.getString(5);
        if(add == null)
            add = CalNames[i];
        else{
            add += CalNames[i];
        }           
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.calendars)).setText(add);

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
```

This will read the calendar entries.

Comment: Hey can you post here whole code. Using this same code I got the error "NullPointer Exceptions" at line "cursor.moveToFirst();". How can I resolve this? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Use Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), new String[]{ "calendar_id", "title", "description", "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }, null, null, null);

Comment: Please tel me how to get that id. I cant get that id.

Comment: How to get google calendar events also in android ...?Is there any parameter for that?please can some one tell me?

Comment: how to initialize the contentresolver here...? i mean ContentResolver cr = ?

Comment: how to get the image from the event using above source ?

Answer (score 1):

For Android 2.2 and above you should use the following URI.

```
Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events")
```

Comment: Do i need a permission to use that?

Comment: Yes obviously

`<uses-permission 
      android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>`