# Retrieving events from Google Calendar in Android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android google calendar API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960560/android-google-calendar-api)

How to retrieve events from **`Android Calendar`** in **`android 2.3`**??
is there any tutorial for this??

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/q/5883938/1160207 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5716257/1160207

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing your code, can I suggest you look at the snippet at the bottom of the following page:

Google Calendar API V3 Events List :

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

I used that and it is working very well for me.

Good luck